# Difference between NumPy.dot() and ‘*’ operation in Python

Tags: python, numpy

On this [page](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-numpy-dot-and-operation-in-python/)
I found that: `v1 * v2 == np.multiply (v1, v2)`

But on another page I found: `v1 * v2 == v1.dot (v2)`

Please, could you explain to me right ?

Comment: That "another page" you're referring to might have been talking about `np.matrix`, which is similar to the usual `np.array` but defines multiplication differently.

Answer (score 1):

[`a * b` is `np.multiply(a, b)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html). [`np.dot`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) is the dot product, which is the same as `np.multiply` *only if* one of the operands is a scalar (a number, as opposed to a vector or a matrix).

### Example with matrices

```
>>> a = np.arange(0, 9).reshape(3, 3)
>>> b = np.arange(10, 19).reshape(3, 3)
>>> a
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
>>> b
array([[10, 11, 12],
       [13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18]])
>>> a * b # elementwise multiplication
array([[  0,  11,  24],
       [ 39,  56,  75],
       [ 96, 119, 144]])
>>> np.multiply(a, b) # elementwise multiplication
array([[  0,  11,  24],
       [ 39,  56,  75],
       [ 96, 119, 144]])
>>> a @ b # matrix multiplication
array([[ 45,  48,  51],
       [162, 174, 186],
       [279, 300, 321]])
>>> np.dot(a, b) # matrix multiplication
array([[ 45,  48,  51],
       [162, 174, 186],
       [279, 300, 321]])
```

Comment: please, why i have the same result in this case :
a=np.matrix(([1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]))
b = np.matrix(([1,2,3]))
print( a.dot(b.T))
>>> [[14]
       [14]
       [14]]
print(a * b.T)
>>> [[14]
       [14]
       [14]]

Comment: @lunched, that's because `np.matrix` is not exactly the same as `np.array`, as jasonharper said in the other comment. For `np.matrix`, `a * b` is matrix multiplication

Comment: we can say ?
```
if A is Matrix and B is Matrix:
    dot(A,B) == A*B and  multiply(A,B) != A*B
    
elif A is Array and B is Array:
    dot(A,B) != A*B and  multiply(A,B) == A*B

elif (A is Matrix and B is Array) or (A is Array and B is Matrix):
        dot(A,B) == A*B and  multiply(A,B) != A*B
```